# How to force-stop an application automatically on startup of an Android TV Box

Tags: android, startup, blocking

I have an application that I need to force-stop automatically on the startup of the Android because it's connecting to the internet and is blocking me the entire TV Box.

I tried to delete it, but I do not have root access and I can't access init.d and system partition. I tried to disable it through task manager and auto start apps, but nothing works. Then, I saw that there is a command by **adb** that could help me to force-stop the app at startup:

```
adb shell am force-stop (package name)
```

Is there a way to execute this command when the TV Box starts so that it force-stops automatically and skips the entire manual process every time I attach the garment? I can think of creating a batch or script file that will run at startup by creating an APK and telling Android to run it at startup.